# Load new HTML page in Parent from iFrame Child

Tags: html, iframe, parent-child

I have an HTML page with an `<iframe>` that loads an HTML form. The form inside the iFrame posts to a PHP script.

Upon completion of the PHP script, how can it load an entirely different HTML page outside of the iFrame?

Answer (score 0):

not in php, php syntax is

```
header( 'Location: url' ) ;
```

but it only works if you havent done anything else yet.

but you can do it with javascript like so

```
document.location.replace("url")
```

or

```
document.location.href = "url";
```

so with php you can write (after form is submitted)

```
echo "<script>document.location.replace('url');</script>";
```

or

```
echo "<script>document.location.href = 'url';</script>"
```

**edit**

i changed `window` (redirects `iframe`) to `document` (redirects page) i should work now, sorry about that.

you can also use `top.window.location` i think.

a simpler way to do this is in the actual html `<form action="url" target="_top">`. however this will skip form-validation.

Comment: Thank you tryingToGetProgreamming. This loads the page after the form is processed, however it's loading in the iFrame. I need this to load in the main browser window.